# Blank screen with opengl es 1.1 android? Also error reporting

Tags: android, opengl-es, error-handling

I have developed a live wallpaper, with opengl es 1.1 and given the API level to be 2.1 and above. It is working in most of the phones. But I have a user comment telling that he got a blank screen and nothing appeared for him. He was using HTC Aria 2.2.2 mobile.

I do not use any kind of compression on texture. And i use very simple open gl code like creating a square with 2 triangle and then rotating it across z axis.

Please let me know what are the situations where the users could see a blank screen. Also let me know if i have to add a specific filter in market to avoid such problems.

I would also like to get some ideas on how to avoid such comments in future. Is there a way where i can detect in my code that there was a error and then pop up a message to send me the report. This will help me to send contact back the users when the error is resolved and ask him kindly to change his comments. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: This might be also be asked on [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue with my HTC Wildfire with certain OpenGL Applications, whenever my phone is too weak in processing power/graphic rendering power the screen will turn black until I shut down the application. Hope this helps.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, that belongs as another question on SO.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, I had intended that comment as a suggestion, not an admonishment.  I am quite aware that you are not the OP.